# Pass parameters to python plumbum command from a list

Tags: python, plumbum

I'm using [Plumbum](https://plumbum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) to run command line utilities in the foreground on Python. if you had a command `foo x y z`, you would run it from Plumbum like so:

```
from plumbum import cmd, FG
cmd.foo['x', 'y', 'z'] & FG
```

In the code I'm writing however, the parameters `['x', 'y', 'z']` are generated into a list. I could not figure out how to unpack this list to send it as parameters to plumbum. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I could have used `__getitem__` for this.
All I had to do was:

```
from plumbum import cmd, FG
params = ['x', 'y', 'z']
cmd.foo.__getitem__(params) & FG
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer Alon Mysore, happened to be what I needed.

I tried the following, (did NOT work):

```
from plumbum import local
from plumbum.commands import ProcessExecutionErr

files = ['gs://some-repo/somefile.txt', 'gs://some-repo/somefile2.txt']
files_string = ' '.join(files)

gsutil = local['gsutil']
command = gsutil['-m', 'rm', files_string]
try:
    job = command.run()
except ProcessExecutionError as err:
    print('Error: {}'.format(err))
    sys.exit(1)
```

But after your answer, here's another example for people reference using gsutil (DID Work):

```
from plumbum import local
from plumbum.commands import ProcessExecutionError

files = ['gs://some-repo/somefile.txt', 'gs://some-repo/somefile2.txt']

gsutil = local['gsutil']
command = gsutil['-m', 'rm']
try:
    job = command.__getitem__(files).run()
except ProcessExecutionError as err:
    print('Error: {}'.format(err))
    sys.exit(1)
```

The issue being that plumbum didn't seem to play nice when I concat'd the list into a string myself.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
from plumbum import cmd, FG
params = ['x', 'y', 'z']
cmd.foo(*params) & FG
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use `__getitem__`, a more readable (and equivalent) solution is `bound_command`:

```
from plumbum import cmd, FG
params = ['x', 'y', 'z']
cmd.foo.bound_command(params) & FG
```